# Is there a method to set background color and border of annotations text?

Tags: google-visualization

I need to set background color and border of annotations used for a Google line chart. Is there a solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't customize the background color or border of the annotations.  You can make a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/list) to add support for it.

Comment: [asgallant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/613559/asgallant), thank you for your help. I'll add a feature request.

Comment: Two years on, you can now do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out HTML tooltips documents on this page: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content

Comment: Yes, I know that the tooltips are customizable, but I need to customize the annotations, but not the tooltips. Thanks for your help!